# API Gateway occasionally spikes 5XX errors in Production

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Our API Gateway and Lambdas are regularly used and work just fine most of the time, however we see spikes in 5XX errors now and then which causes a spike in customer complaints and other issues. When I look at the logs during this time I see a flood of the following error:

```
Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
```

There are no other details beyond this. After 10 or 15 minutes it will go away along with customer complaints. I've read that it may happen if you exceed your concurrency limit, but looking at the dashboard and it doesn't look like we ever break above 150 concurrent executions.

The calls themselves being hit work consistently as well, aside from these random spikes in 5XXs.

What else might be causing this inconsistency?

Looking through logs to try and get this figured out. I have made the logs as verbose as possible and there is nothing there. We'll have a normal call with a success response then a few minutes later this error comes up with no other logging, just the error alone. Then a few minutes after that we have logs starting for the next successful call.

```
10:25:42 Successfully completed execution
10:25:42 Method completed with status: 200
10:42:01 Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda 
proxy response
12:21:21 Successfully completed execution
12:21:21 Method completed with status: 200
```

Logging can't go further because the lambdas are never even executed.  So we have no details on the payload sent to it, or any internal logging for the call, etc.  It just immediately fails at the API Gateway level.

Edit: We still get these spikes but we are working on splitting the lambdas out more.  We have an ExpressJS app that handles the lion's share of all requests.  So we are breaking more off, especially high traffic requests, into their own lambdas to see if this helps.  In-case there is an issue where a container gets too backlogged or times-out because it was handling long running requests (that takes upwards of 20s) as well as being hammered by requests that finish < 500ms.

Other theory is that maybe there is an error that gets triggered somewhere that kills the process or something else and that container is bad until it gets destroyed and respawned.  As these spike and then go away in a few minutes.  So breaking the lambdas up more should reduce the odds of errors from one cascading and impacting all other requests.

We also increase the resources of the lambda to see if that would help with it handling so many requests.

Comment: Are your Lambda functions accessing some external resource? Can it be that they're timing out or being throttled?

Comment: This particular call just talks to an RDS database.  And done so in a way that the connection is shared at the container level so all requests have that same connection.  It's a rather active call, but it works at a very high percentage.  These spikes only happen every few days maybe.

Comment: Either there's some obscure function in your code that is messing with your lambda return value (an unexpected exception maybe) or your lambda is timing out. Those are the only things I can think of, sorry

Comment: Contact the AWS support. That's most likely an AWS Lambda internal problem they need to solved on their end. We've had a very similar situation a while ago as well.

Comment: Hi,
I checked my lambda's metrics, and it didn't throw any error. Its max execution duration peaked at 300ms, which is much lower than the API Gateway's _Maximum integration timeout_ (30s). 
What could have caused the 5xx errors detected at my API Gateway level?

Comment: @galeop I have similar issue as well. My lambda populates SQS queue and max execution duration is less than 2s. I still get occasional peak in 5XX errors. The 5XX  API call doesnt reach lambda at all. Have you found the root cause of this issue ?

Comment: Yes I have. The problem was caused provisioned concurrency. Errors returned by API Gateway due to the inability of the backend lambda to respond to load of requests will not necessarily be 429, but can also be 5xx. I know it's weird. Maybe the lambda responded to API Gw a 429, but API Gw responds to the client a 5xx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when there is a timeout with your call and if there is a delay with your lambda execution.

If you are accessing an external resource such as RDS or an external network call, wrap that with a promise and handle with a timeout. This way you can identify which resource is having a bottleneck or taking a long time to execute.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) { 

var response = {}; // set the response object
var err = "An error occured";

setTimeout(function () {                                                                                
            callback(err, response);                                                             
        }, 3000); // 3000 ms is the timeout
}

// Actual code here

};
```

Also, check for any missing callbacks. That will also cause this issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark this as the best answer so far.  Particularly the "missing callbacks".  We broke our lambdas up, increased resources, etc but also found a use case where errors were not triggering the callback.  So there is a case of a cascading error that could really mess up a container for future requests.  System has been much more stable after making all those changes.